# Weird behaviour between Record<string, unknown> and Record<string, any>

Tags: javascript, typescript

I came across the below function.

```js
function fn(param: Record<string, unknown>) {
  //...
}

x({ hello: "world" }); // Works fine
x(["hi"]); // Throws -> Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'string[]'
```

It makes sense because the `Index Signature` in `Array` is `Number`, But in `Record` it is defined as `string`.

**But**

If I change the `unknown` with `any`,

```js
function fn(param: Record<string, any>) {
  //...
}

x({ hello: "world" }); // Works fine
x(["hi"]); // Also works fine
```

**The Question Is:** The `Key` type isn't changed at all in `Record`, Only the `Value` is changed to `Any`. Still, the `Index Signature` in `Array` is `Number` but in `Record` it is `string`. But why I am not getting any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a historical reason for this behavior. `Record<string, any>` was often used to describe object types before the `object` type existed. The type was handled specially by the compiler to a point where any non-`null` and non-`undefined` object types were assignable to it and the reasoning behind this being that the type of any property in an object is guaranteed to be compatible with `any` (See [#33786](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33786#issuecomment-538005806)). To preserve compatibility, this behavior has not changed.

Using `Record<string, unknown>` (and any other types except `any`) will require the source type to have a *string index signature*. Since arrays don't have one, passing them as an argument fails.